# include referenced rows without referencing rows

Tags: mysql, join

So, i need to fetch a bunch of fields from one table and a where-claus which requires fields from a different table so i'm using JOIN for that, although when i use a join statement and specifying an ON condition only rows from my referenced table that has a row in the referencing table is included, but i want all rows from the referenced table to be included.

Here's my MySQL trimmed down a tiny bit:

```
SELECT derp.*
    FROM derp 
    JOIN herp 
    ON herp.id=derp.id
WHERE derp.approved!=2 OR (derp.member='462' OR herp.approver='32523')
ORDER BY member,startDate
```

Now only rows from derp which has a pointer from herp will be included, i want all rows

EDIT: This is answered by using LEFT JOIN

Comment: Have you tried `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: Well look at that! Amazing how embarrassing a question can be :D thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer

```
SELECT derp.* FROM derp 
LEFT JOIN herp ON herp.id=derp.id
WHERE derp.approved!=2 OR (derp.member='462' OR herp.approver='32523')
ORDER BY member,startDate
```